# "XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0" when calling ElementTree.parse

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

[`ElementTree.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) fails in the simple example below with the error

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: XML or text declaration not at start of entity: line 2, column 0

The XML looks valid and the code is simple, so what am I doing wrong?

```
xmlExample = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    stuff
</data>
"""
import io
source = io.StringIO(xmlExample)
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(source)
```

Comment: I also tried saving the xml into a file and open the file.xml... still failed.

Comment: This can happen also when you receive a file or stream that starts with blank spaces.

Answer (score 43):

You have a *newline at the beginning of the XML string*, remove it:

```
xmlExample = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
...
```

Or, you may just `strip()` the XML string:

```
source = io.StringIO(xmlExample.strip())
```

As a side note, you don't have to create a file-like buffer, and use [`.fromstring()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring) instead:

```
root = ET.fromstring(xmlExample)
```

Comment: How do you remove the blank space before the first element?

Answer (score 9):

Found it... whitespace in front of 1st element...

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlExample = 
"""
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data></data>
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xmlExample.strip())
```

You can try this. This worked for me.